# How to save docker image and DB in docker?

Tags: docker, save

I am a new one in dockers so it is probably dumb question, but I couldnt figure it out.

I am using Docker Toolbox (windows 10 home) to learn dockers. I build docker on mysql image, created DB, conneted to DB by python. Everything works fine.

But every time I turn off my computer, I have to pull images again, run docker etc.

What is a good practice to save progress on dockers and not to lose any data and waste time :D?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the image will be lost，but the container will exit. After restarting, you can find your original container using:

`docker ps -a`

and then start it:

`docker start YourContainerName`

Comment: Nope. I tried docker ps -a. It shows me an empty table.